# Is vitiligo inherited from one generation to a later one?

Tags: dermatology, genetics, melanin, vitiligo, carrier-genetic

There seem to be many testimonies on the internet that suggest that vitiligo is heritable <sup>1</sup>. According to a Quora answer <sup>2</sup>, there is apparently a 5% chance of transferring vitiligo to your kids. Yet, I haven't been able to find studies to confirm or reject this idea.

I read that some studies suggest that certain genes such as COMT, PTPN22, and NALP1 are possibly linked to vitiligo <sup>3</sup> <sup>4</sup>. Does that automatically make it transmittable by heredity, if so, do both parents need to be carrier of a certain gene variant?

Also, how likely is it to transmit when only one of the parents carries those risk markers?

---

<sup>1 http://www.viticlear.com/hereditary.asp</sup>
<sup>2 https://www.quora.com/Is-vitiligo-an-inheritable-disease</sup>
<sup>3 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3132901/</sup>
<sup>4 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3521835/</sup>

Comment: I do not really understand why this question gets down voted without feedback. Fine to down vote a question but then at least leave a comment with feedback.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote either but downvotes without explanation are a fact of life on all stackexchange sites. It could be due to weak prior research. Adding link(s) to where you read that "some studies suggest" would greatly improve your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory ah, same old. I will try to do this more consistently on all answers and questions. Better now?

Comment: Yes, much better. +1